# Android TextView: text is cut off

Tags: android, textview

I'm experiencing some weird behavior of TextView with weight and many lines of text:

[image]

As you can see, last line of text is cut off. What I want is ellipsizing the text on the end of the previous line (quis...). My code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/events_item_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/events"
    android:padding="@dimen/events_item_padding"
    android:src="@drawable/donations_image" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/events_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n\nAt vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/events_item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Some text on the bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**SO, I'VE ENDED WITH THIS CUSTOM VIEW:**

```
public class ShrinkingTextView extends TextView {

private int measuresLeft = 3;

public ShrinkingTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ShrinkingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    measuresLeft--;
    if (measuresLeft <= 0) {
        if (getLineCount() * getLineHeight() > getMeasuredHeight()) {
            setText(getText().subSequence(0, getText().length() - 4) + "...");
            measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a way to do it :

```
private void fixTextCutting(final TextView text) {
    ViewTreeObserver vto = text.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        private int maxLines = -1;
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (maxLines < 0 && text.getHeight() > 0 && text.getLineHeight() > 0) {
                int height = text.getHeight();
                int lineHeight = text.getLineHeight();
                maxLines = height / lineHeight;
                text.setMaxLines(maxLines);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a maximum number of lines for your TextView, try this instead :

Use this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/events_item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:text="@string/your_text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and set your number of lines programmatically if needed.

Comment: Alternatively: android:lines

Comment: But I want different lines number for different orientations and image proportions..

Comment: Then set this value programmatically based on the orientation etc.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with some code? As far as I see it should be a custom shrinking TextView.. And text should be cut in the loop until view height is satisfied?

Comment: You could try to calculate the number of lines yourself, or try to implement this, which I think is pretty neat : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwE61B56pVQ

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global layout listener for a TextView in any type of ViewGroup.  I'd point out the importance of removeOnGlobalLayoutListener especially if you are using the listener in an Adapter for a RecyclerView or ListView.

```
    final TextView dSTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.annoyingTextView);
dSTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        dSTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        float lineHeight = dSTextView.getLineHeight();
        int maxLines = (int) (dSTextView.getHeight() / lineHeight);

        if (dSTextView.getLineCount() != maxLines) {
            dSTextView.setLines(maxLines);
        }

    }
});
```

You can read more about it [here](http://blog.jimbaca.com/2016/03/14/global-layout-listener-to-the-rescue-how-to-fix-the-textview-cutoff)